# NSubstitute - mock throwing an exception in method returning void

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, void, nsubstitute

Using NSubstitute, how do you mock an exception being thrown in a method returning void?

Let's say our method signature looks something like this:

```
    void Add();
```

Here's how NSubstitute docs say to mock throwing exceptions for void return types. But this doesn't compile :(

```
    myService
        .When(x => x.Add(-2, -2))
        .Do(x => { throw new Exception(); });
```

So how do you accomplish this?

Comment: Remove arguments because your method doesn't have them

Answer (score 17):

Remove arguments from `.Add` method in substitute configuration.
Below sample will compile and work for void method without arguments

```
var fakeService = Substitute.For<IYourService>();
fakeService.When(fake => fake.Add()).Do(call => { throw new ArgumentException(); });

Action action = () => fakeService.Add();
action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentException>(); // Pass
```

And same as in documentation shown will compile for void method with arguments

```
var fakeService = Substitute.For<IYourService>();
fakeService.When(fake => fake.Add(2, 2)).Do(call => { throw new ArgumentException(); });

Action action = () => fakeService.Add(2, 2);
action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentException>(); // Pass
```

Assumes that interface is

```
public interface IYourService
{
    void Add();
    void Add(int first, int second);
}
```